# Oracle or operator is not working

Tags: oracle

I am trying to search for a records have one match or more form the sent values in query I have this table

```
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
|  1 | Joe  |
|  2 | noe  |
+----+------+
```

this is the query i am  using

```
SELECT
*
FROM
members
WHERE
(
    UPPER( NAME ) LIKE(
        '%' || UPPER(:NAME )|| '%'
    )
    OR :NAME IS NULL
)
AND(
    ID = :ID
    OR :ID IS NULL
)
```

if I am replacing the :NAME with 'joe' and the :ID with '0' it does not return any record, while I need to get the first row

and if I am replacing the :NAME with '' and the :ID with '1' it return the 1st row

What is the right query or what is the right replacement should be?

Comment: There is no record with `id = 0` and `0 != NULL`, so `0 IS NULL` is FALSE

Comment: Or more simply, 0 is not `NULL`.

Comment: You need to pass `:id` as either `1` or `null`. Or, add another condition so that 0 matches 1 or whatever the rule should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has two filters combined with a Boolean AND operator. This means it returns a record when there is one which matches **both** criteria.

Your first pair of parameters matches no records because (as @jurgend points out) `0` is not a null so `0 is null` is false. The second pair returns a record because you are passing a null (Oracle treats empty strings as null, which catches newcomers out). So it matches the second record on `ID = 1`.

If you want to match on :NAME you need to pass `null` for :ID.

If you need to match records on the basis of either parameter then you may need to rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
members
WHERE
(
    :NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND   
    UPPER( NAME ) LIKE
        '%' || UPPER(:NAME )|| '%'
)
OR
(
    :ID IS NOT NULL
    AND ID = :ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't very smart, but perhaps might help. The idea is to "substitute" (using the NVL function) a missing value with something that doesn't exist in a table. For an ID, I choose "-1", and "x" for NAME.

```
SQL> with test (id, name) as
  2  (select 1, 'joe' from dual union
  3   select 2, 'noe' from dual
  4  )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where nvl(id, -1) = nvl(&id, -1)
  8     or nvl(name, 'x') = nvl('&name', 'x');
Enter value for id: 1
Enter value for name:

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         1 joe

SQL> /
Enter value for id: ''
Enter value for name: noe

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         2 noe

SQL> /
Enter value for id: 1
Enter value for name: noe

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         1 joe
         2 noe

SQL> /
Enter value for id: 0
Enter value for name: joe

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         1 joe

SQL>
```